# Cannot import matplotlib in Paraview

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import, paraview

I am trying to make a figure using matplotlib in Paraview as discussed on page 73 of the user manual. I am running Paraview 5.2.0 64-bit on Windows 10. A minimal example is:

```
def setup_data(view):
    pass

def render(view, width, height):
    from paraview import python_view
    figure = python_view.matplotlib_figure(width, height)
    ax = figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    return python_view.figure_to_image(figure)
```

This however results in a black screen in the Python view and the following error in the output window:

> Error: Cannot import matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg
>
> Error: Cannot import matplotlib.figure.Figure

How to fix this?

Comment: answering to own question ??

Comment: @Surajano - yes, it is [explicitely](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) encouraged

Comment: Hi. The problem still exists in ParaView 5.3.0. We'll try to resolve it in 5.4, which is due out in early June, 2017.

Comment: Hi. I still have the problem in ParaView 5.6.0, the solution is not implemented yet? It solved using the procedure below.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it turns out that matplotlib fails to load when it cannot import the `dateutil` module during import of the agg backend. Running `pvpython` and specifically importing the agg backend from matplotlib yields:

```
>>> import matplotlib.backends.backend_agg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.2.0-Qt4-OpenGL2-Windows-64bit\bin\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 31, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
  File "C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.2.0-Qt4-OpenGL2-Windows-64bit\bin\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 18, in <module>
    from axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.2.0-Qt4-OpenGL2-Windows-64bit\bin\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 19, in <module>
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
  File "C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.2.0-Qt4-OpenGL2-Windows-64bit\bin\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 119, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY, \
ImportError: No module named dateutil.rrule
```

Specifically importing `dateutil` shows it is not installed:

```
>>> import dateutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

Unfortunately, my `pvpython` runs version 2.7.3 so `pip` is not installed by default and i found installing `pip` to be difficult with `pvpython` in Windows 10. Instead, i downloaded [`python-dateutil 2.6.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.6.0) and extracted only the folder `dateutil` from the zip archive into the pvpython library folder located at:

```
C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.2.0-Qt4-OpenGL2-Windows-64bit\bin\lib\site-packages\
```

Restarting Paraview then gave me a figure in the Python view instead of a black screen.